# Does openstreetmap API supports two points data?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

recently I want to get the information from openstreetmap.
I want to get the route and distance between two point.

I can get one point data by doing this:

def get(address, verbose=False):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl

serviceurl = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/'

parms = {}
parms['route'] = address
parms['addressdetails'] = 1
parms['country'] = 'Japan'
parms['format'] = 'json'
parms['limit'] = '1'
url = serviceurl + '?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)
print(url)

data = []
if verbose: print('Retrieving', url)
uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
if verbose: print('Status', uh.status)
if uh.status==200:  data = uh.read().decode()
if verbose: print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')

try:
    js = json.loads(data)[0]
except:
    js = None

if not js:
    print('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
    print(data)
    return {}

return js
```

So I can get the information by doing this:

```
get('Osaka Castle')

#result
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?route=Osaka+Castle&addressdetails=1&country=Japan&format=json&limit=1
{'address': {'country': '日本', 'country_code': 'jp'},
 'boundingbox': ['20.2145811', '45.7112046', '122.7141754', '154.205541'],
 'class': 'boundary',
 'display_name': '日本',
 'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png',
 'importance': 0.8710133265462459,
 'lat': '36.5748441',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '139.2394179',
 'osm_id': 382313,
 'osm_type': 'relation',
 'place_id': 235505229,
 'type': 'administrative'}
```

However, if I want to find a route or distance between two points.
How can I break the url link?

For example, how can I break the url link and get information from this link?
https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_car&route=34.69%2C135.53%3B34.66%2C135.50#map=15/34.6741/135.5168

Thanks a lot!!